# не удалось загрузить изображение через ajax в Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, изображения, upload

У меня есть функция, которая создает форму в div-блок. При изменении ввода файла я хочу загрузить изображение и отправить на сервер для сохранения.

```
$(document).on("change","#image-load",function() {
    readURL(this);
})

function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            var img = '';
            var now = $.now();
            if($(".gallery-avatar").length > 0) {
                img = '<div class="gallery-item"><img src="'+e.target.result+'"></div>';
            } else {
                img = '<div class="gallery-item gallery-avatar"><img data-id="'+now+'" src="'+e.target.result+'"></div>';
            }
            $(".gallery").append(img);

            saveImage(now);

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
function saveImage(time) {
    var formData = new FormData($("#insert-gallery")[0]);

    $app.request("/admin/images/"+gallery_id,"PUT",formData,false,false,function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

На сервере код выглядит так:

```
public function putImage(Request $request) {
        $id = $request->route("id");

        if($id > 0) {
            if($request->hasFile("image")){
                $file = $request->files("image");
                $name = md5($file->getClientOriginalName()).time()."jpg";
                $file->move(base_path("/public/images"),$name);
                $image = new Images();
                $image->path = $name;
                $image->product_id = $id;
                $image->save();
                return response()->json(["status" => true,"id" => $image->id]);
            }
            return response()->json(["id" => $request]);
        }
        return response()->json(["status" => false]);
    }
```

но `$request->hasFile()` возвращает `false`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: "/admin/images/"+gallery_id,
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```